# JS dropdown menu being hidden? or not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After thoroughly trying to fix this issue - I need a little help.

I am trying to make a website that has a navbar (made with bootstrap) for websites and I am making a small drop-down menu for smaller screens (I haven't added this functionality yet, I just want it to work first). I haven't styled it much yet either.

The problem is that I *know* my button and code is working (because I have a [codepen](https://codepen.io/zaenaria/pen/OOZOBY) showing that it works), but in my website, I cannot see the drop-down menu. Not sure if it is hidden or what but I just can't figure this out.

Here is the HTML (because I have to put something...):

```
<div class = "dropdown">
    <button onclick = "menuBtn ()" class = "dropBtn">Menu</button>
    <div id = "dropCollapse" class = "dropdownContent">
        <a class = "contentLinks" href = "#about">About</a>
        <a class = "contentLinks" href = "#team">Team</a>
        <a class = "contentLinks" href = "#photos">Photos</a>
        <a class = "contentLinks" href = "#shirts">T-Shirts</a>
        <a class = "contentLinks" href = "#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have played around with z-index (in a number of places but if you have a suggestion, feel free to make it and I will try it). I have taken the menu out of the navbar (thinking it had something to do with that). But mostly I am just confused - nothing else really answered my question about this menu issue. I feel like there is something small that I am overlooking and I just can't figure it out.

Here is a fiddle showing the basic outline of my website with the menu not working: https://jsfiddle.net/nekochan/eh69segg/1/

Comment: In the fiddle your html seems to be malformed, you have an `navBrand` anchor without closing it, also the spacing between your html attributes and definition eg. `class = "` should be `class="` try fixing up that first should help debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things I noticed:

- you were using jQuery but did not define jQuery to load.  If you do an "inspect element" you'll see that $ is not defined
- also you had a few missing divs, and an anchor wasn't closed
- I'd recommend just using purely jQuery if you're going to go that approach - it's a very simple example.  Here is your updated fiddle - notice the toggle animates nicely :)

https://jsfiddle.net/qdL9mch2/1/

```
/* global $ */
$(document).ready(function() {

  //makes the masethead fit the whole screen
  $("#masthead").css("min-height", $(window).height());

  //mobile menu button collapse
 $(".dropBtn").on("click", function(){
    $("#dropCollapse").toggle("show");
});

  // Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
  //update to jquery
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropBtn')) {

      var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdownContent");
      for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
          openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        }
      }
    }
  };

});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! The missing tags were a copy paste issue into the fiddle (I'm building it elsewhere) - it must have been the JS. And you are very right that the JQuery works better :)

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple errors there in your HTML for example `<a class="navBrand" href="#masthead">` is not closing and your `menuBtn` is not being called, I would recommend you to use jquery completely if you have it included inside your project see here your code working

```js
//mobile menu button collapse
function menuBtn() {
  document.getElementById("dropCollapse").classList.toggle("show");
}
/* global $ */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#my-button").click(function() {
    document.getElementById("dropCollapse").classList.toggle("show");
  })
  //makes the masethead fit the whole screen
  $("#masthead").css("min-height", $(window).height());



  // Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropBtn')) {

      var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdownContent");
      for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
          openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        }
      }
    }
  };

});
```

```css
.main {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.body {
  position: relative;
}

#navBar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
}

.brandImage {
  height: 60px;
  width: auto;
}

#navHeader {}

#navItem {}

#navLink {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropBtn {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropBtn:hover,
.dropBtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdownContent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 9999;
}

.contentLinks {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.contentLinks:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 960px) {
  #large-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .brandImage {
    float: left;
  }
}

#masthead {
  background-color: #65737e;
  background-image: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/285286/pexels-photo-285286.jpeg);
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.headerText {
  font-size: 90px;
  font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
  color: #fff;
}

.headerTagline {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
  color: #fff;
}

.anchor {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.sectionHeader {
  font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.sectionText {
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

#aboutBox {
  background-color: #c0c5ce;
  padding: 20px 0 20px;
}

#teamBox {
  background-color: #a7adba;
  padding: 20px 0 20px;
}

#workBox {
  background-color: #65737e;
  padding: 20px 0 20px;
}

#shirtBox {
  background-color: #4f5b66;
  padding: 20px 0 20px;
}

#socialBox {
  background-color: #343d46;
  padding: 20px 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="navBar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navHeader navbar-left">
        <a class="navBrand" href="#masthead"></a>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="large-menu">
          <li class="navItem">
            <a class="navLink" href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="navItem">
            <a class="navLink" href="#team">Team</a>
          </li>
          <li class="navItem">
            <a class="navLink" href="#photos">Photos</a>
          </li>
          <li class="navItem">
            <a class="navItem" href="#shirts">T-Shirts</a>
          </li>
          <li class="navItem">
            <a class="navLink" href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropBtn" id="my-button">Menu</button>
        <div id="dropCollapse" class="dropdownContent">
          <a class="contentLinks" href="#about">About</a>
          <a class="contentLinks" href="#team">Team</a>
          <a class="contentLinks" href="#photos">Photos</a>
          <a class="contentLinks" href="#shirts">T-Shirts</a>
          <a class="contentLinks" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </div>
      </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container text-center" id="masthead">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h1 class="headerText"></h1>
      <p class="headerTagline"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <span class="anchor" id="about"></span>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="aboutBox">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h2 class="sectionHeader">About Us</h2>
        <p class="sectionText">We're all about that chedda</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <span class="anchor" id="team"></span>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="teamBox">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h2 class="sectionHeader">Meet the team</h2>
        <p class="sectionText">pictures of team go here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <span class="anchor" id="photos"></span>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="workBox">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h2 class="sectionHeader">Our Work</h2>
        <p class="sectionText">pictures go here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <span class="anchor" id="shirts"></span>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="shirtBox">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h2 class="sectionHeader">T-shirts Preview</h2>
        <p class="sectionText">pictures of tshirts go here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <span class="anchor" id="contact"></span>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="socialBox">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h2 class="sectionHeader">Contact Us</h2>
        <p class="sectionText">links to social media and contact us form</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```